# Allow copying files with scp without allowing users to log in and launch a shell

Tags: server, bash, ssh, scp

Is there a way to allow a user to access the server with scp, but without having premission to log in and launch a shell?

The thing is that I want the better connection type with key files for all users using at the moment the ftp server services, to improve stability and security (to get rid of pass auth).

So the question is how can I configure ssh to do this?

I wanted to pass use the following destination where all users can share their files with each other:

```
/usr/share/files
```

Comment: related: [Allow SFTP but disallow SSH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh), [Allow SCP but not actual login using SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh)

Comment: both point on centos, and not on ubuntu

Comment: it's only a matter of configuration, no distribution-specific. It will work on ubuntu

Comment: rssh is a bit outdated ... think package `rush` brings about the same capabilities

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your users should be able to do. Do you want to let them upload and download files? Only download? Only upload? Do you ened `scp` or is `sftp` perhaps a better choice?